# Rails 3 Error Checking for Existence of Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I has a model "modela" that has a has_many_through relationship with model "submodelb". In a controller I want to check if modela has any submodelb associated with it. I have tried the two code examples below; however, the both throw the error "undefined method `submodelbs'" if modela does not have any submodelbs. Please help me see what I am doing wrong.

Sample 1:
      if !@modela.submodelbs.nil?
          @submodelbs = @modela.submodelbs
         else
           @submodelbs = []
         end

Sample 2:
       if !@modela.submodelbs.empty?
          @submodelbs = @modela.submodelbs
         else
           @submodelbs = []
         end

Comment: undefined method `submodelbs` means that `@modela` was probably nil

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Why not just put your checks in a `begin...rescue...end` block?

Comment: I'd just like to mention that this is an absolutely inappropriate way to solve OP's problem and anyone reading this should certainly do something similar to the other answers. I apologize for such a poor solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.present?` which is the opposite of `blank?`

```
@submodelbs = @modela.submodelbs.present? ? @modela.submodelbs : []
```

But I think your problem is that `@modela` may be `nil` or you may have not defined associations correctly in the model.

Answer (score 1):

The reader method produced by `has_many_through` always returns something that looks like an Array, so it should never return nil. So, can't you just return `@modela.submodelbs` always?

Comment: Yeah..you are right..it returns `[]` in case of no associated records..I missed that while answering...

Answer (score 0):

I use blank?

```
unless @modela.submodelbs.blank?
   #modela has submodelbs
end
```

but error messege suggests that you may have something wrong with association definition...

Also what you are trying to achieve can be done with one-liner

```
@modela.submodelbs ||= []
```

if submodelbs are nil empty array will be assigned.